Visual Studio/Intellisense auto-populating issue
Snippet from Visual Studio illustrating issue, ""Console.WriteLine(value: $"{decimalNotation:X}");""
Learning basics--have not encountered this issue before. I'm guessing it's Intellisense auto-populating "value: " in front of whatever I want to print. It's annoying and unwanted.
Please share if you know how to fix this. Thank you!
I've messed around in the Intellisense settings and can't find anything to disable this from populating. Just backspacing/deleting doesn't help--it just re-appears. Have also deleted my cache to help reset.

It's not actually in the source file, it's a hint by Visual Studio telling you the name of the argument. If you look at the saved file with a simple text editor, there is no value: in there. (It could be, since C# allows out-of-order setting of arguments, which is why VS considers the hint useful.) I have no idea how to disable it, though.

That solved it! Thank you so much!
